# How do I calculate correlated color temperature correctly?

Tags: image-processing, color

How can I calculate the color temperature(CCT) of the light source illuminating a given raw image correctly?

The method I used is proposed by McCamy, and the algorithm was also described in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature). The problem is that I don't know whether should I apply white balance process before calculating CCT.

If it should not, how do I get the conversion matrix that convert the current device-dependent RGB color space to CIE XYZ to calculate the algorithm correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that I don't know whether should I apply white balance process before calculating CCT.

Definitely not. Afterwards, the light source would have a completely different color profile, depending on how you implement white balance, and hence, a different color temperature.

> If it should not, how do I get the conversion matrix that convert the current device-dependent RGB color space to CIE XYZ to calculate the algorithm correctly?

Get the color profile (which might be much more complex than a simple matrix) of your device; usually, that means getting the ICC file for your camera/scanner/sensor, and applying that to convert your image from the device color space to something canonical.

If your camera/scanner/sensor doesn't have such a profile, you will need to calibrate it first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I'm the developer of the camera... so I need to find the solution by myself. And I don't know the "normal way" that used by the other developers. Please give me some hints to calibrate the data. ><

Comment: Well... read up on color calibration, then :) Basically, you can order calibrated color sheets, use a light source of known color temperature and calibrate the camera yourself, creating a color profile on the go. With that, you're definitely leaving the scope of dsp.SE; I'd recommend asking on the photography stackexchange sites; pretty sure there's someone out there who actually has done this before :)